# How to use views and difference operator. MY SQL

Tags: mysql

say we have Tables R1 and R2 both with a column (name)

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    R1

MINUS

SELECT
    name
FROM
    R2;
```

How would I do this in MySQL since "MINUS" does that work over there?

Comment: Refer this link : http://gokhanatil.com/2010/10/minus-and-intersect-in-mysql.html

Comment: "MINUS" is not supported in MYSQL

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r1 MINUS r2 :

```
SELECT r1.name
FROM r1 LEFT JOIN r2
ON r1.name = r2.name
WHERE r2.name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOT IN** - will return the `names` from table `R2` which are not in table `R1` :

```
SELECT name
FROM R2
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM R1)
```

Comment: Even if your code snippet solves the question, it would be recommended to describe what you did...

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks for you guidance :)